# How to Pass hidden variable using displaytag

Tags: java, spring, displaytag

I am developing application using spring web mvc..

For displaying purpose i am using displaytag library..

Here is the code for that :

```
<display:table uid="intf" name="${model.interfacesList}" id="interfacesList"  pagesize="5">

  <display:column property="id" title="ID" />
  <display:column title="Name" property="name"/>
  <display:column title="IPAddress" property="ipAddress"/>
  <display:column title="Network Mask" property="networkMask"/>
  <display:column title="Edit" media="html" style="text-align:center;" >
  <a  href="javascript:submitForm();"><span> <img src="/MailServerV2/images/Btn_edit.gif"/> </span></a>
   <input type="hidden" id="id" value="${intf.id}" name="id"/>
   <%--<input type="hidden" id="id" value="${model.interfacesList.id}" name="id"/>--%>                                                                                                         
</display:column>

</display:table>
```

At the time of submitting form i am using get method..

in ${intf.id} case : I am getting id as a blank ('') value.

in ${model.interfacesList.id} case : I am getting

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
```

Can anybody please tell me how can I pass hidden pass selected ID of particular row ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" value="${interfacesList.id}" name="id"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function in your DisplayTag Wrapper that generates the html output and access the request parameters. (assuming ID is in the request, where does it come from?)

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)getPageContext().getRequest();

int lId = request.getParameter("id");
...
out.append("... type='hidden' id='lId' ...);
```